# Pause all the running Threads after a memory crosses a given threshold

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a requirement , where I have a multithreaded java application, and I want to monitor the memory usage as well in the application. I want to pause all the running threads in the executor service , as soon as the memory reaches beyond 90%. Below is a sample code , I have written , however , I am not sure , how to pause the threads.I am trying to poll every minute to check the memory utilization , however not sure how to pause all the threads in the executor service.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PauseThreads {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    exec.submit(new Workers());
}


ScheduledExecutorService schedule = (ScheduledExecutorService) Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
schedule.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();


        long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();

        if( (allocatedMemory / maxMemory ) > 0.9 ){
            //pause all the threads running under the exec
        }

    }

},  0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
}

class Workers implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {

    // do some work

}

}
```

Please suggest , what changes are required to be made , or if there is any other better approach.Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you rethink what you are trying to do.  Measuring the utilisation give no indication of how much memory would be retained after a GC which is usually what matters.  If all you need is to know what the threads are doing, you can take a stack trace of each thread.   I also suggest that if you are trying to solve a memory allocation issue you are better off using a profiler as this is what it is designed to do.

Comment: What should happen once all the threads are paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `ReentrantLock` as in the following example. Your `Worker` threads will need to occasionally call the `check()` method

```
public class MemoryAwait {

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition memoryAvailable = lock.newCondition();


    public MemoryAwait() {
        ScheduledExecutorService schedule = (ScheduledExecutorService) Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        schedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (enoughFreeMemory()) {
                    memoryAvailable.notify();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void check() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            while (!enoughFreeMemory()) {
                memoryAvailable.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private boolean enoughFreeMemory() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        return allocatedMemory / maxMemory < 0.9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to monitor the heap usage, but...

...You say "pause" like it's something one thread is going to do to another.

Bad Idea.

If you are a thread, and you're hogging all the memory, what good would it do if I could "pause" you?  How can you release any of the memory that you're using while you are "paused?"

What you want is for each worker thread to do something like this:

```
while (true) {
    waitUntilTheresEnoughAvailableResources();
    acquireSomeResources();
    doAUnitOfWorkWork();
    freeResources();
}
```